# bukkit - Give certain permissions to target

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm developing a Bukkit plugin and I need help giving permissions to certain player. To explain a bit more, some admin will use a command with one argument (a player), and then that player needs to receive some permissions. How can I do this?

What I have so far:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("giveallkits") || sender.hasPermission("ekits.command.giveallkits")) {
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "The console should not play. It would be so OP..");
        return true;
    }
    if (!sender.hasPermission("ekits.permission.giveallkits")) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~ " + ChatColor.GOLD + "You can't to use this command.");
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "(Error 01(No Permission))");
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if(args.length == 0){
        //send the sender an error message, and return true

        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Correct usage: /" + commandLabel + " <player>");
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
    if (target == null) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~ " + ChatColor.GOLD + "Player not specified");
    } else {
        // Then how to give the permissions here?
player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "~ " + ChatColor.GOLD + "You gave " +       ChatColor.BOLD + target.getDisplayName() + ChatColor.GOLD + "all kits");
     }
     } return true; 
 }
```

Comment: you can use PEX and PEX API

Comment: I Know, but I like to have 0 dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try this function on target, it should do the work for you:
(You should check your first if statement. && makes more sense)

```
/**
 * Adds a new {@link PermissionAttachment} with a single permission by
 * name and value
 *
 * @param plugin Plugin responsible for this attachment, may not be null
 *     or disabled
 * @param name Name of the permission to attach
 * @param value Value of the permission
 * @return The PermissionAttachment that was just created
 */
 public PermissionAttachment addAttachment(Plugin plugin, String name, boolean value);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I messed up the &&. What is the permission in this attachment?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere to set or unset the permission in it.

Comment: I could not understand that tutorial, sorry. Could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: You could use it in that way: target.addAttachment(this, "ekits.permission.giveallkits", true); and add the returned PermissionAttachment to a Map<UUID, PermissionAttachment> in case you want to remove it. (The UUID from the target)